# Handling the button click event inside my angular Ng-Dialog modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I am having a Angularjs application. I have a form on click of the submit button I am opening a `ngModal` popup. I do not know how to handle the button click event which is present inside the modal window. I have attached the code below for reference:

Inside my controller:

```
 $scope.ModelValue="Username:"
 $scope.displayModal = function () {
        ngDialog.open({template: 'app/modal/modal.html', scope: $scope});
    }
```

Inside my Modal.html

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header primary">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmation</h4>
    </div>
    <div id= "modal-section" class="modal-body">
      {{ModelValue}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside my directive:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('modal', function ($parse) {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
      '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
        '<div class="modal-content">' +
          '<div class="modal-header">' +
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
            '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace:true,
    scope:true,
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.title = attrs.title;
      scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
        if(value == true)
          element.modal('show');
        else
          element.modal('hide');
      });
      $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
        });
      });

      $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Please let me know how to handle the Confirm and Close button event click. On Confirm button click I need to handle the event inside my parent controller from where I opened the dialog box.

Comment: create a `controller` for this directive and write code for the methods in that controller

Answer (score 0):

Call button click as defined below

```
<div class="ngdialog-buttons col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

 <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-secondary" ng-click=closeThisDialog("Cancel")>Cancel</button> 

 <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary" ng-click=updateForm()>Save Changes</button>

 </div>
```

Comment: Where  do I need to write the `updateForm` and `closeThisDialog ` functions. I mean in which controller?